# Reader character encoding problems in Oracle layers with where parameters in FME Desktop

Tags: fme-form, query, oracle-spatial

I am using FME Desktop 2020 and trying to read an Oracle layer with -where- condition but i have problem because it failed with reading of character Ë or Ç.

I get this error:

ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated'

If I replace Ë with E, it is ok. Find below part of the error log.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a character set issue: the literal in the SQL statement string is generated in a character set that does not seem correct. That happens in the layer of code in FME that constructs this statement. How do you pass the literal ('K?LCYR?') ? Is this something you type in ?

Comment: When passing string literals to the Oracle database, those strings are either expected to be in the database character set, or a specific character set, specified via the `NLS_LANG` environment variable. Is this set anywhere ? If so, to what ?

Comment: You can find out the character set in your database by doing: `SQL> select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';`

Comment: NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16. I insert ('KELCYRE') as parameter like my_field=('$P1'). I use the published user parameter created inside fme. If i insert it directly, not as parameter everything is OK.

Comment: That means that the database expects the string literal to be passed in UTF8 encoding. Is the value of that parameter prompted from the end-user ? Or is it passed from some text file ?

Comment: prompted from the end user

Comment: Then it seems to me like a problem with FME when prompting character input. The log you show is odd too. Is that a log file ? I mean a text file written by FME ? In what character set is this file written ? And what is the character set and locale of your desktop/laptop ?

Comment: But at the end, I suggest you call Safe support on that one, or look in their community exchanges. There must be many other customers doing the same ...